# Javascript. Creating two buttons with different urls. But the last button made overwrites the old button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

My code have a button that can print a file to a pdf form (it works fine). Now I want to add another button that just print it in a html page. I have added the new button and it works too.

The problem is that now when I have created a new button, it will now overwrite it method on the old one. So both button will do the same thing. (Both print it in html form)

Here are some part of my code:

The function for the invoice datatable looks like this:

```
function invoiceDatatable(tableId, extras, url, optionParser) {
 var options = $.extend(true, {}, documentOptions, {
  tableId: tableId,
 url: url || '/api/invoices/?type=i',
  extras: extras
});
```

Here i create both buttons, with their url - the code always use the last created one:

```
options.tasks.push({
url: '/print_to_pdf',
queryParam: 'documents',
label: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print pdf'
});

options.tasks.push({
url: '/print_to_html',
queryParam: 'documents',
label: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print html'
});
```

Finally the code for the tasks of the buttons looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < self.tasks.length; i++) {
var task = self.tasks[i];
var taskButton = $('<button type="button">' + (task.label || task) + '</button>');
taskButton.addClass('btn btn-default');
$(taskButtons).append(taskButton);
if (task.action) {
  // An entry point for custom actions
  $(taskButton).click(function(){
    task.action(self.selected);
  })
} else {
  $(taskButton).click(function () {
    var downloadUrl = task.url + '?' + task.queryParam + '=' + self.selected.join(',');
    downloadUrl += "&ordering=" + self.ordering()['ordering'];
    $(infoPanel + ' .alert').remove();
    $(infoPanel).append('<div class="alert alert-info">' +
      '<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i> Building document' +
      '</div>');
    $.ajax(downloadUrl, {
      success: function (data) {
        function doPoll(url, success) {
          $.ajax(jobUrl, {
            type: "HEAD",
            success: function (pdfData, status, xhr) {
              if (xhr.status == 202) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                  doPoll(url, success)
                }, 2000);
              } else {
                success()
              }
            }
          });
          $.ajax(url, function (data) {
            alert(data);  // process results here
            setTimeout(doPoll, 5000);
          });
        }
```

How do I fix my code so that each button have its own functionality?

I think it is the push method that overwrites the action. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an encapsulation issue due to the fact that variable declarations are hoisted (and aren't scoped to the `for` loop). Instead of a `for` loop, use `.forEach`:

```
self.tasks.forEach(function(task) {
    var taskButton = $('<button type="button">' + (task.label || task) + '</button>');
    taskButton.addClass('btn btn-default');
    ...
});
```

This wraps your entire button building code into its own scope for each button.

If you can't support `.forEach`, use an immediately-invoked anonymous function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < self.tasks.length; i++) {
    (function() {
        var task = self.tasks[i];
        var taskButton = $('<button type="button">' + (task.label || task) + '</button>');
        taskButton.addClass('btn btn-default');
        ...
    })();
}
```